# Аналог setTimeout в Java

Tags: android, java

Мой слушатель ChangeListener срабатывает за секунду кучу раз, а мне нужно из этой кучи только самое последнее его срабатывание (чтоб не плодить кучу запросов). Если бы я писал программу на JavaScript, то я бы каждое срабатывание обрабатывал функцией setTimeout с 1 секундой интервала, если бы за этим срабатыванием следовало следующее, то я бы отменял выполнение первого setTimeout и устанавливал новое, в итоге за секунду выполнялось бы только одно срабатывание. Как мне реализовать такое в Java?

Вот тут `filtrRequestAdres(center);` запускается кучу раз. Как в нем реализовать отфильтровывание срабатываний onCameraChange?

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition pozCamera) {

                filtrRequestAdres(center);

        }

    });

public void filtrRequestAdres(LatLng center) {

       // if(...) {    startIntentService(); }

}
```

Как отложить выполнение функции в Java и как отменить отложенное выполнеиние функции? И чтоб на работу программы задержки не влияли. :)

Вот такая вещь почти решает мой вопрос:

```
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.i("tag", "This'll run 300 milliseconds later");
    }
}, 300);
```

Она откладывает выполнение, но как отменить это отложенное выполнение?

Comment: то, что Вам нужно - это Handler. В частности метод [postDelay](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)).

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо, а как отменить выполнение отложенного?

Comment: а Вы попробуйте в приведенной ссылке глянуть чуточку ниже, в следующий метод, который называется removeCallbacks.

Comment: @Геннадий Козлов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Можно обойтись и без хендлера. Все намного проще.

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
        long previousSystemTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //Объявляем поле, которое будет хранить предыдущее время срабатывания

        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition pozCamera) {
                if((System.currentTimeMillis() - previousSystemTime) > 1000) { // если текущее время минус предыдущее больше 1000 миллисекунд
                    filtrRequestAdres(center); // то делаем, что надо
                    previousSystemTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // и записываем новое значение предыдущего времени
                }

        }

    });
```

Comment: А какой способ использовать лучше этот или с postDelay? Что будет более производительней?

Comment: А если в эту секунду собьется системное время?

Comment: @Flippy, System.currentTimeMillis() не имеет отношения к тому, что вы называете системным временем.

Comment: Как бы, напрямую имеет.

Comment: @Flippy, как же оно может сбиться?

Comment: @Flippy, вообще, я в этой помойке (ru.stackoverflow.com) больше не отвечаю, тут модераторы умственно отсталые

Comment: @Flippy, если каким-то образом собьется системное время, то любое другое (кроме внешнего источника) время в телефоне собьется тоже, и единственным вариантом останется запрашивать время из внешнего источника.

Answer (score 1):

Есть метод setTimeout() в библиотеке [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java).

Пример с кодом:

```
final Integer[] counter = new Integer[] {0};
Supplier<Void> incr = new Supplier<Void>() {
    public Void get() {
        counter[0]++;
        return null;
    }
};
U.setTimeout(incr, 100);
```

Выполнение начнётся через 100 мс в новом потоке.